# How to search a site using google data API

Tags: search, google-sites, google-data-api

I want to write an app that access my site at sites.google.com.

The API provides access to the site's feeds, but I couldn't find a way to use the search features to find pages that contains a given word.

Can this be easily done via the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use Sites API to search using the following URL,
       **https://sites.google.com/feeds/content/YOUR_DOMAIN/SITE_NAME?q=YOUR_WORD**

and you can also specify which type of page you want to search as follows,
       **&kind=webpage at the end of your URL**.

Try this.

It is documented in below url,
     **https://developers.google.com/google-apps/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#ContentFeedQueries**

In the section,
 **Full text search**.It is stated that,
  To search across the entire content of a site, use the q parameter to issue a full-text search:
           **GET   /feeds/content/domainName/siteName?q=Text%20I%20am%20looking%20for**

Comment: Will try. Is this documented anywhere?